# How to calculate the curl of unti vector and the expression as follows？

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I have a expression as follow, and how to simplify further？ and how to calculate the curl of unti vector $ \nabla \times \hat r$ in the expression , where $ \hat r=\vec r/|r| $ and  $ \vec  r=x\hat i+y\hat j+z\hat k. $
 $$\nabla\cdot(-\hat r\times (\hat r\times \vec A))=(\hat r\times \vec A) \cdot (-\nabla \times \hat r)+\hat r\cdot((\nabla \times \hat r )\times \vec A)=?$$

Comment: The vector triple product in your expression is ambiguous as written due to the fact that the vector cross product is not associative. By $\hat r\times \hat r\times \vec A$ do you mean $\hat r\times \hat (r\times \vec A)$ or $(\hat r\times \hat r)\times \vec A$?

Comment: $ \hat r \times  \hat r \times \vec A $ mean   $\hat r \times ( \hat r \times \vec A )$, otherwise $\hat r \times \hat r= 0$ makes the expression no meaning.

Comment: $\vec\nabla\times\hat r =0$ if $r\ne0$.